# AWS IoT simulator - How to forward messages from a topic created in MQTT test client to a Kinesis stream

Tags: amazon-web-services, mqtt, aws-iot, aws-iot-core

I am trying to use the https://aws.amazon.com/solutions/implementations/iot-device-simulator/ and am able to see the messages streaming to a topic in the MQTT test client. The topic is called /test/devicesimulator.

I created an IoT rule to forward messages to a Kinesis data stream and the rule just says :

SELECT * FROM '/test/devicesimulator'
The attached role seems to have the permissions to write to the destination kinesis data stream.

I seem to get nothing on the stream though.

My question is:

Is it even possible to create an IoT rule for a topic created in the MQTT test client? If yes, Does my SQL query look like what it should be?

If not, what's the alternative to this?

I am Sorry I am new to IoT and trying to put pieces together. What do I need to change to get this working?

0 Commen

Answer (score 1):

Have you checked CloudWatch Logs? You can check rule execution status when you send a message. Run the follwing command and look for `"eventType":”RuleExecution”` in the log.

```
aws logs tail --follow AWSIotLogsV2
```